# Autofocus not working onkeyup event using ipad/iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a web application in which registration form I have a field for phone number. Infact its consists of three text boxes. 1st and 2nd text box allows 3 digits to enter and 3rd text box allows 4 digits to enter as phone number. I have JS function that checks if 3 digits are entered in the 1st box then it auto focus onto the 2nd box. if 3 digits are entered in the 2rd box then it auto focus to 3rd box. This functionality is working in IE, Firefox chrome.

But when I try to run this application through iPhone or Ipad then is not working, after entering the 3 digits in 1st text box I am expecting it to auto focus onto the 2nd text box but it does not. I manually tap the 2nd box and then enter data in that 2nd box.

Here is how it works on iphone.

On the Iphone, the first three digits get entered and the Touchscreen keypad stays open. As soon as you go to enter the 4th digit (expecting it to move to the next field) the keypad disappears. In order to get to the next field, you must TAP on the field to bring the Keypad back and the cursor then goes to that field. The same thing happens going to the next field as well.

Here goes the definition of the function that I am using onkeyup

```
function chkLengthPhone(){
    if(document.getElementById('ph_no1').value.length == 3)
{
        document.getElementById('ph_no2').focus();
}
if(document.getElementById('ph_no2').value.length == 3)
{
    document.getElementById('ph_no3').focus();
}
```

}

Any suggestions please.?

Answer (score 1):

I used the onKeyPress event instead of onKeyUp.